# Sudden change in the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, wavefunction

Could someone explain what this sentence mean? "If the Hamiltonian changes suddenly by a finite amount, the wavefunction must change continuously in order that the time-dependent Schrodinger equation be valid"?

I am guessing that such a change describes a square-well change? And is it saying that ${\partial \psi(x,t)\over\partial t}$ has to be continuous in such a case? Thanks.

Comment: If Hamiltonian changes suddenly, the wave function time *derivative* does too, so it is not continuous. It is the wave function itself who is continuous: $\psi(t) = \int_{t_1}^t H\psi(t')dt'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct. Continuous $\psi(x,t)$ (as a function of time) is by definition wavefunction with finite time derivative. Time derivative is finite because Hamiltonian is finite (due to time-dependent SE).